# Nothing but DHCP works after testing SR-IOV on Mellanox ConnectX-4 Lx

Tags: vlan, proxmox, openvswitch, mellanox

I was following the [Proxmox guide](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/PCI(e)_Passthrough) for enabling PCIe passthrough and SR-IOV for my NIC, since I am running Vyos in a VM as a router. However, after undoing all the changes the NIC is not working anymore. The only thing that seems to be working is DHCP (and not DHCPv6) when directly connecting another computer. I suspect it might be because I've setup a DHCP relay, since the port I connected to has a different VLAN (10) than the DHCP server (12).
Here's output from `tcpdump -e`:

```
98:03:9b:b7:f7:ea > ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 362: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), 10.10.10.115.68 > 255.255.255.255.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 98:03:9b:b7:f7:ea, length 316
fe:63:6d:d4:da:18 > 2a:a2:54:7e:47:45, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 373: vlan 12, p 0, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), 10.10.12.1.67 > 10.10.12.5.67: BOOTP/DHCP, Request from 98:03:9b:b7:f7:ea, length 327
fe:63:6d:d4:da:18 > 98:03:9b:b7:f7:ea, ethertype 802.1Q (0x8100), length 395: vlan 10, p 0, ethertype IPv4 (0x0800), 10.10.10.1.67 > 10.10.10.115.68: BOOTP/DHCP, Reply, length 349
```

I also tried clearing the DHCP lease from the server, and it still worked and assigned a new address.

After getting the address from DHCP I'm unable to ping the gateway at 10.10.10.1 from 10.10.10.115. I tried `arping` from the router, and it does not succeed. However when inspecting the traffic with wireshark, I can see an ARP reply from 10.10.10.1 after who has 10.10.10.1. The client (98:03:9b:b7:f7:ea) shows up as stale in the router ARP table, but everything seems ok from the client side.

I also have setup the other port on the NIC as a trunk, and connected that to a switch, however in that case even DHCP does not work. Another 1G NIC on the motherboard with the same configuration on the Proxmox host works as expected.

I tried resetting the NIC to defaults during the boot menu, and also using the `mlxconfig -d <dev> reset`. Before messing with SR-IOV it was working as expected, so I'm guessing I messed something up, but at this point I'm not sure what.

Here's my `/etc/network/interfaces` from the Proxmox host

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto enp39s0
iface enp39s0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
#Trunk 1G

auto enp45s0f0np0
iface enp45s0f0np0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
#Trunk 25G

iface enp42s0f3u5u3c2 inet manual

auto enp38s0
iface enp38s0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr1
#WAN

auto enp45s0f1np1
iface enp45s0f1np1 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
        ovs_options tag=10 vlan_mode=native-untagged
#Users

auto intport01
iface intport01 inet static
        address 10.10.16.30/24
        gateway 10.10.16.1
        ovs_type OVSIntPort
        ovs_bridge vmbr0
        ovs_options tag=16
#MGMT

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
        ovs_ports intport01 enp39s0 enp45s0f0np0 enp45s0f1np1
#Inside

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet manual
        ovs_type OVSBridge
        ovs_ports enp38s0
#WAN
```

`enp45s0f1np1` is the port on which DHCP worked on, `enp45s0f0np0` is the other port on the non-working NIC. On the router `vmbr0` is added as a NIC, and the VLANs are setup there.